# How to enable javascript function in datatype call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code

```
function loadPage(url) {
    url = url.replace('#page', '');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page=' + url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (parseInt(msg) != 0) {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }
        }
    });
}

$(".pageclose").click(function () {
    $(".backscreen").animate({ "left": "100%" });

});
```

and This is the code to open the next page without loading. but I can not activate **.pageclose**.. `<div class="pageclose"> close </div>` exist on other pages. but when I put the page, the code **pageclose** can not function. Why?

*note : im using this code http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/

Comment: Are you sure you run your register your handler after DOM is loaded? With jQuery, check if handler registration takes place after page has been loaded: $(document).ready(function(){ bla bla })

Comment: sure, im using this 
`$(document).on('click','.pageclose',function() {
});` but cant working

Comment: end this u mean `$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $(".pageclose").click(function() {
  $(".backscreen").animate({"left": "100%"});

 });
});` not working

Comment: ok now working, i using old jquery :D sorry